# Chosen module not working in drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

i used to [Chosen 7.x-2.x-dev module](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) and then installed. In  config/user-interface/chosen is the default. But it is not working. Can anyone tell me why and how to handle not.

Comment: Please define "it is not working"; as it is, the question is rather broad and the users who answer would end up copying the full module documentation.

Comment: It works fine for me, so once you have **specific** question about configuration or library or something, there is a chance i might help.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [Chosen 7.x-2.0-beta4](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen). In **Home » Administration » Configuration » User interface » Chosen** add your selct fields id in **Apply Chosen to the following elements** fields as **select#your-field-id**.

[image]

Another method is select **Apply** option in your **Select fields edit form**

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes. I'm tried with [chosen jquery](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen)  but failed

Comment: did u installed chosen module..?

Comment: Oh. By I used improperly library should such error. Thank you very much